# how do you reference a pom.xml file from a custom xml file in the same directory?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I have 2 pom.xml files: the parent pom.xml file (called pomp.xml) and the default pom.xml file.

C:\pomp.xml:

```
          <project ....>
          <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

          <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
          <artifactId>app</artifactId>
          <version>test</version>
          <packaging>pom</packaging>

            <modules>
              <module>my-app</module>
            </modules>
          </project>
```

C:\my-app\pom.xml

```
          <project ...>
            <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

            <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <packaging>jar</packaging>
            <dependencies>
              <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.8.2</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
              </dependency>
            </dependencies>
          </project>
```

If I run "mvn package -f pomp.xml" the above works. However, if I were to move pomp.xml to the same directory as pom.xml, it doesn't work.

Is what I am trying to accomplish possible? if so, how?

Comment: What's your ultimate purpose? Multi-module projects are expected to live in directories, otherwise what's the point of keeping things separate?

Comment: You are fighting with Maven, and it is legendary for fighting back. Just call them all 'pom.xml' and don't try to co-locate them. Heaven help you if you try to use the release plugin in this scheme of yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it without modifying the child xml file. I just entered a ., to indicate the current directory, under module.

Answer (score 1):

Set relative path to your parent

```
<parent>
   ...
   <relativePath>./pomp.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```